# $\rho\to \pi\pi$ parity

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, parity, pions

I'm having some difficulty understanding why the $\rho^0$$\rightarrow$$\pi^+ \pi^-$ decay conserves parity.

By my understanding, the parity of a meson is given by $P_aP_b(-1)^{L+1}$ and the parity of a two-body state is given by $P_cP_d(-1)^L$

Angular momentum of $\rho=1$ and spin of $\pi=0$ so the final state must have $L=L_{\pi^+}+L_{\pi^-}=1$

Thus total parity for the final $\pi^+\pi^-$ system is given by

$P_{\pi^+}P_{\pi^-}(-1)^L=P_uP_\bar{d}(-1)^{L_{\pi^+}+1}P_{\bar{d}}P_d(-1)^{L_{\pi^-}+1}(-1)^1=1$

since fermions and antifermions have parity $1$ and $-1$ respectively

But the parity of $\rho=-1$ if $L_{\rho}=0,S_{\rho}=1$ so parity isn't conserved

What am I missing?

Comment: It's unclear what you are throwing on the table indiscriminately. The parity of ρ  is -1, and that equals that of the ππ state, (-)(-)(-)=-, the last - from the L=1.   As a *separate* point, reassure yourself the parity of the ρ is -1. Its constituents are in a spin triplet, L-singlet (s-wave) state, so its parity is -1.

Comment: I understand why $P_{\rho}=-$, but could you please explain why the $\pi\pi$ state is also $-$, without prior knowledge of pion parity? As I say in my question, assuming the parity of a fermion is $+$ and an antifermion $-$, the equation stated gives parity of the final state as $+$.

Comment: ? the parity of the π is the same as that of the ρ for the same reason: s-state. Think of parapositronium versus orthopositronium.  The only non vanishing *L* is in the spatial wavefunction of two pions. That is my *point* about the deep malformation of your question.

Answer (score 3):

I am summarizing my comments only to prevent the systematic abuse of a terminology malforming the question; in particular, its erroneous  $L=L_{\pi^+}+L_{\pi^-}=1$ part.

Indeed, the (intrinsic) parity of a meson is  $(-1)^{L+1}$ where *L* is the angular momentum of the wavefunction of the quark-antiquark pair. Both the orthoquarkonium and the paraquarkonium, the $\rho$ and the $\pi$, are in s-wave, so, then, the respective *L*=0 ; and they consequently both have negative parity, $P_\rho=P_\pi=-1$. It is the spin wavefunction that gives the $\rho$ its *J* and denies it to the pions, but that does not affect parity.

Since the  parity of a two-body state is given by $P_cP_d(-1)^L$, and the *L* of the two-pion wavefunction =1, so as to produce a *J*=1 particle out of two spinless particles, 
$$
P_{\pi\pi}=P_\pi P_\pi (-)^{-1}=-1 =P_\rho,
 $$
as required in a strong decay.

Comment: FYI, my question comes directly from a degree program question paper with solutions, so I'm unsure what exactly you're referring to with regard to erroneous information.

Comment: I'm not *that* interested, but it might help (if the bizarre erroneous equation I single out above were part of a writeup by a responsible party) to quote it so as to note the context of it. I suspect no instructor wrote it down.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out what I was missing was the presence of a gluon decaying into a $d\bar{d}$ pair, with the gluon adding an extra $(-1)$ term to the total parity equation.